# Action Bar Sherlock, install

Tags: android, eclipse, actionbarsherlock

i have next situation, i want to use ActionBarSherlock. I read next instruction

```
"Download the .zip/.tgz and extract it somewhere 
Go to eclipse and choose File->New->Project 
Choose Android Project 
Select Create project from existing source and then browse to the library folder inside the folder you just extracted the .zip/.tgz into "
```

But there is no Android Project when I go to File->New-Project. How to make it?
If i choose New-Android Aplication Project, there is no option "Select Create project from existing source"

Comment: Just import the project inside library.

Comment: Did you install the Android SDK?

Comment: http://androidfragments.blogspot.com/2011/10/how-to-use-actionbar-sherlock.html look this. in file-new there are: Android Application project, test project and other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File - New - Other and here you import as a project from existing code. BTW this is a good start: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FKd1yVpIXHo

(of course if you do not have Android Project, only Java Project it seems you forgot to install the Android SDK)